# Changing the result of a select with multiple fields based on conditions (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, select, case

I have this script:

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_CODE, LINK_NUMBER, INTERNAL_REFERENCE, PORTFOLIO_CODE, FILE_CODE, CMP_CODE, COUNTERPARTY_CODE, TRX_AMOUNT, CONVERT(varchar, BEGINNING_DATE, 3) AS 'BEGINNING_DATE', CONVERT(varchar, BOOK_DATE, 3) AS 'BOOK_DATE', 
             CONVERT(varchar, END_DATE, 3) AS 'END_DATE', AMORT_FREQUENCY, END_OF_MONTH, NUMBER_OF_AMORT_PERIODS, CONVERT(varchar, FIRST_REDEMPTION_DATE, 3) AS 'FIRST_REDEMPTION_DATE', AMORT_PREPAID_FLAG, AMORT_CALC_MODE, 
             AJUST_FIRST_AMORT_FLAG, AMORT_CALC_RATE, AMORT_RATE_INCREMENT, AMORT_FIRST_ANNUITY, AMORT_FIRST_REDEMPTION, INTEREST_FREQUENCY, CONVERT(varchar, FIRST_INT_DATE, 3) AS 'FIRST_INT_DATE', NUMBER_OF_INT_PERIODS, INT_PREPAID_FLAG, 
             INT_CALC_BASIS, INT_RATE_TYPE, INT_FIXED_RATE, INT_MARKUP, INT_FLOOR, INT_CEILING, REFERENCE, PAYMENTS_CMP_ACC, AMORT_CMP_ACC, INT_CMP_ACC, FEE_CMP_ACC, NOTE_1, ADDIT_PAYMENT_CMP_ACCOUNT, ZU_01, ZU_02, ZU_03, ZU_04, ZU_05, ZU_06, 
             ZU_07, ZU_08, ZU_09, ZU_10
FROM   LOANS
WHERE (LAST_VERSION_FLAG = - 1) AND (NUMBER_OF_PAYMENTS = 1) AND (PERIOD_DEFERRED_FLAG = 0) AND (TRX_CATEGORY = 75) AND (AMORT_CALC_MODE IN (0, 2, 3))
```

I would like to add a condition that would make the field  AMORT_FREQUENCY behave as this:

WHEN O THEN 3
WHEN 1 THEN 2
WHEN 2 THEN 1
ELSE 0

I have tried CASE but I can't figure out how to make it work. I am sorry if this is a very basic question.

Thanks in advance.

Mario.

[ADDED]

The field AMORT_FREQUENCY can contein this values: 0, 1, 2, 3
I want to change the output value of this field:

When the field contains 0, change to 3
When the field contains 1, change to 2
When the field contains 2, change to 1
When the field contains 3, change to 4

In this select I am extracting a huge table and I need those values to be changed.

Comment: Please provide a *bare minimum* query that represents your problem.

Comment: could you provide example input and output? i'm not quite clear with *"when O then 3 when 1 then 2."*

Comment: Hi, I have added more information, i hope it is enough.

Comment: anyway, you can do something like `case AMORT_FREQUENCY when 'O' then 3 when  '1' then 2... end` but given we don't know how `AMORT_FREQUENCY` looked like (is it a varchar? a number? a char?) we can only do wild guesses. oh right, is that zero or a letter O?

Comment: AMORT_FREQUENCY is smallint

Comment: `case AMORT_FREQUENCY when 0 then 3 when 1 then 2 when 2 then 3 when 3 then 4 end` doesn't work?

Comment: I am a newbie so please forgive my questions. Should i add it in the select part of the script? something like SELEC FIELD1, FIELD2, CASE AMORT_FREQUENCY... AS AMORT_FREQUENCY?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) this way:

```
select
  AMORT_FREQUENCY,
  case AMORT_FREQUENCY
   when 0 then 3
   when 1 then 2
   when 2 then 3
   when 3 then 4
  end as amort_new
from test
```

See fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/ITjjwjTx

You can then put the `CASE` part into your query by replacing the `AMORT_FREQUENCY`, something like (added parentheses for readability):

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_CODE, LINK_NUMBER, INTERNAL_REFERENCE, PORTFOLIO_CODE, FILE_CODE, CMP_CODE, COUNTERPARTY_CODE, TRX_AMOUNT, CONVERT(varchar, BEGINNING_DATE, 3) AS 'BEGINNING_DATE', CONVERT(varchar, BOOK_DATE, 3) AS 'BOOK_DATE', 
         CONVERT(varchar, END_DATE, 3) AS 'END_DATE', (case AMORT_FREQUENCY when 0 then 3 when 1 then 2 when 2 then 3 when 3 then 4 end), END_OF_MONTH, NUMBER_OF_AMORT_PERIODS, CONVERT(varchar, FIRST_REDEMPTION_DATE, 3) AS 'FIRST_REDEMPTION_DATE', AMORT_PREPAID_FLAG, AMORT_CALC_MODE, 
         AJUST_FIRST_AMORT_FLAG, AMORT_CALC_RATE, AMORT_RATE_INCREMENT, AMORT_FIRST_ANNUITY, AMORT_FIRST_REDEMPTION, INTEREST_FREQUENCY, CONVERT(varchar, FIRST_INT_DATE, 3) AS 'FIRST_INT_DATE', NUMBER_OF_INT_PERIODS, INT_PREPAID_FLAG, 
         INT_CALC_BASIS, INT_RATE_TYPE, INT_FIXED_RATE, INT_MARKUP, INT_FLOOR, INT_CEILING, REFERENCE, PAYMENTS_CMP_ACC, AMORT_CMP_ACC, INT_CMP_ACC, FEE_CMP_ACC, NOTE_1, ADDIT_PAYMENT_CMP_ACCOUNT, ZU_01, ZU_02, ZU_03, ZU_04, ZU_05, ZU_06, 
         ZU_07, ZU_08, ZU_09, ZU_10
FROM   LOANS
WHERE (LAST_VERSION_FLAG = - 1) AND (NUMBER_OF_PAYMENTS = 1) AND (PERIOD_DEFERRED_FLAG = 0) AND (TRX_CATEGORY = 75) AND (AMORT_CALC_MODE IN (0, 2, 3))
```

Comment: one last question. One of the fields might have a value or be null. I want to change the output so that it shows 0 when it is null and 1 in any other case.

I am trying with what you told i am using this:

CASE CL_CODE WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

But it always returns 1.

Comment: @MarioDuran have you tried `case when CL_CODE is NULL then 0 else 1 end`?